# Why is the time to the next reaction in a stochastic simulation an exponential disbtribution?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

The title basically says it all, I am reading about stochastic simulation and each article/book I read says the time until the next reaction is given as and $Exp(h_i(x,c_i))$ where $h_i$ is our stochastic rate law (hazard), $c_i$ is the stochastic rate constant and $x$ is the current marking of the system.

When reading about this the literature just says that the time to next reaction is given as an exponential distribution, but I do not understand why. I have seen some things mention poisson process, but I don't know why I just assume that the system is a poisson process.

Comment: Are the processes **first-order** reactions?

Comment: Its a mixture of first order and second order reactions

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the field that you are describing (from what I found on a quick web search, it is chemical kinetics), however the process as described defines an in-homogeneous Poisson process. Whilst I cannot concretely help with your context, perhaps the below helps to motivate the definition.

The exponential distribution is a canonical choice of distribution for waiting times between points (*reactions* as you call them above). This is because exponential waiting times have the *memorylessness property*.

In short, this says that the time left to wait for a reaction to occur is independent of the time already waited. In notation, if $T$ denotes the time between two reactions then this says

$$\mathbf P (T > t \, | T > s) = \mathbf P( T > t - s ), \qquad t > s.$$

The only continuous distribution with this property is the exponential distribution.

---

**Two ways to define the Poisson Process**

One angle that might help is to note that there are two ways to define a (homogeneous) rate $\lambda > 0$ Poisson process.

1. **Via the Poisson Distribution.**
   This approach determines the Poisson point process as being the unique distribution of points $X = \{x_i\}_{i=1}^\infty \subset \mathbf R$ such that the number of points in any (measurable) set $A \subset \mathbf R$ satisfies
   $$\mathbf P( \# \{X \cap A \} = n) = e^{-\lambda |A|} \frac{(\lambda |A|)^n}{n!},$$
   that is, the number of points in $A$ is poisson distributed with rate $\lambda |A|$, where $|A|$ denotes the lebesgue measure of $A$; so if $A = [a,b]$ is an interval then $|A| = b- a$.
2. **Via Exponential Waiting Times**. The second approach defines the points $X = (x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ by setting
   $$x_i = J_i + x_{i-1},$$
   where $x_0 = 0$ (which is not a point of $X$), and each $J_i \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ is an independent exponential variable.

The point here is, if you think that your source is referring to the exponential waiting times as a property (rather than the definition), then perhaps the first definition will be clearer from the text.

Proving that these two definitions are equivalent takes a bit of work, but is a standard exercise in probability.

Comment: Yeah I am working with chemical kinetics, but that should no effect the maths? It's just the book I am reading says that it's obvious that the time to a next reaction follows an exponential distribution and to be honest I do not understand why

Comment: What is the book; I might be interested to take a look if I can find it.

Comment: The book is called stochastic models for systems biology by Darren Wilkinson. In the second version of the book, page 180 on mass-action stochastic kinetics mentions it, as does page 182 on the Gillespie algorithm. There's also a part on page 87 which just explains that if we have a poisson process then the time to next reaction is $Exp$ distribution